# Call WCF Service through AJAX Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wcf

AJAX, JSON etc, so pardon if I am wrong anywhere and feel free to correct me in that case.

My Question being:

I am trying to call a WCF service through jQuery .ajax() method through client side scripting but am getting error 500 - internal server error for some reason I am not sure of.

Mentioned below is my code for the WCF with the interface for ServiceContract, its implementation in a class, the Service Host file and the web.config settings for the service that I am using followed by the client side scripting for JQuery .ajax() method and the mark up for the page. Please could anyone of you point out as to where and what am I doing wrong.

My WCF interface:

```
<ServiceContract(Namespace:="Service")>
  Public Interface IPMSService
    <OperationContract()>
    <WebInvoke(Method:="POST", RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json,  BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)>
    Function InsertNewOrUpdateStaffRecord(ByVal Staff As Staff) As Integer
  End Interface
```

Class implementing ServiceContract:

```
      <AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode:=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)>
    Public Class PMSService
        Implements IPMSService

        Public Sub New()
        End Sub

        Public Function InsertNewOrUpdateStaffRecord(ByVal Staff As Staff) As Integer         Implements IPMSService.InsertNewOrUpdateStaffRecord
            Return New StaffManager().InsertNewOrUpdateStaffRecord(Staff)
        End Function
    End Class
```

The Service Host Directive:

Web.Config settings for WCF:

```
    <system.serviceModel>
       <behaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="Service.NewServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
              <enableWebScript />
              <webHttp />
              <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <bindings>
          <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="defaultRestJsonp" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">
              <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="64" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
              <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
          </webHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" 
    multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
        <services>
          <service name="Service.PMSService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
            <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="Service.NewServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
        binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="defaultRestJsonp" contract="Service.IPMSService" />
          </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

My client side code for ajax call :

```
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "http://ddsdev.i-jag.local:82/Newservice.svc/InsertNewOrUpdateStaffRecord/",
            data: Staffdata,
            processData: false,
            dataType: "json",
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function (response) {
                OnSuccess();
            },
        });
```

Note: I have hosted the service on IIS. Also Staff is a custom class that I have created and StaffData - the data I am trying to pass in ajax is a javascript object that I have created which maps to the Staff object in the service.

I have been trying to fix this issue that I am facing for the past several hours going through several links but no luck as my understanding of these concepts are only up to the fundamental level.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: 500 internal server error could be generated by an exception in service method. Have you tried putting your service contract implementation method in try catch block and writing error somewhere to check it? Or have you tried debugging service?

Comment: Also could you please post you Staff class implementation? Maybe it is not marked with DataContract attribute or some of its members not marked with DataMember attribute?

Comment: I have marked my Staff class with DataContract and DataMember attributes, any how here is a sample code for your reference:            DataContract()>
        Public Class Staff    Private _StaffId As Integer
    <DataMember()>
            Public Property StaffId() As Integer
        Get
            Return _StaffId
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _StaffId = value
        End Set
    End Property        End Class

Comment: I am sorry it is not formatted properly